# The structures or STL containers?

Tags: c++, coding-style, code-structure

Which approach is better to use in C++ to create the type `House`,

```
struct Coord {
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
};
struct House {
    string number; // example: 17A
    vector<Coord> coordinates;
    bool isCompletelyStraight;
};
```

or

```
using Latitude = double;
using Longitude = double;
using Coord = pair<Latitude, Longitude>;
using Number = string; // example: 17A
using IsCompletelelyStraight = bool;
using House = tuple<Number, vector<Coord>, IsCompletelelyStraight>;
```

?

Comment: Code 1, because code 2 is nonsense (and not really the same)

Comment: #1. I don't like `pair`, it doesn't convey very much in the way of meaning.

Comment: Objects are good because of encapsulation.  The first one encapsulates better.  It's far more readable.

Comment: `pair` is **not** a general replacement for a struct that happens to have two items. It's for generic programming where you have to deal with types that aren't known at the time you write the code. Stick with `struct Coord`.

Answer (score 4):

The first approach is alot easier to maintain, that's why I would always go for that. The second approach is like using templates when you don't really have to.

A pair is not a good idea because you would have to use them like`coordinates[i].first, coordinates[i].second'` while it's more clean to just have the Coord structure and access a vector element like `coordinates[i].latitude, coordinates[i].longitude`

What about something like this:

```
using Latitude = double;
using Longitude = double;

struct Coord
{
    Latitude latitude;
    Longitude longitude;
};

using CoordsContainer = vector<Coord>;

struct House {
    string number; // example: 17A
    CoordsContainer coordinates;
    bool isCompletelyStraight;
};
```